# UWP XAMARIN crashes in RELEASE mode (but good working in debug)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, uwp, xamarin.uwp

I use Xamarin Forms, UWP Project. In my Project I have file embedded as resources. In debug mode it compile and working good, but in release mode it crashes. What can I do?
I tried many tips, but nothing helped.

[image]

My errors:

```
Вызвано исключение: "System.IO.FileNotFoundException" в System.Private.Reflection.Core.dll
Вызвано исключение: "System.IO.FileNotFoundException" в System.Private.Reflection.Core.dll
"project.UWP.exe" (Win32). Загружено "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.dll". Загрузка символов пропущена. Модуль состоит из машинного кода, а отладка машинного кода в данный момент отключена.
"project.UWP.exe" (Win32). Загружено "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\DWrite.dll". Загрузка символов пропущена. Модуль состоит из машинного кода, а отладка машинного кода в данный момент отключена.
"project.UWP.exe" (Win32). Загружено "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Windows.Globalization.dll". Загрузка символов пропущена. Модуль состоит из машинного кода, а отладка машинного кода в данный момент отключена.
Вызвано исключение: "System.AggregateException" в System.Private.Threading.dll
Вызвано исключение: "Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException" в Microsoft.CSharp.dll
Вызвано исключение: "System.Reflection.MissingMetadataException" в System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Дополнительные сведения: Reflection_InsufficientMetadata_NoHelpAvailable: EETypeRva:0x0001e930. For more information, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=623485

Вызвано исключение: "System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException" в System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Вызвано исключение: "System.Reflection.MissingMetadataException" в System.Linq.Expressions.dll
Дополнительные сведения: Reflection_InsufficientMetadata_NoHelpAvailable: EETypeRva:0x0001e930. For more information, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=623485

Вызвано исключение: "System.Reflection.MissingMetadataException" в Newtonsoft.Json.dll
Дополнительные сведения: Reflection_InsufficientMetadata_NoHelpAvailable: EETypeRva:0x0001e930. For more information, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=623485

Вызвано исключение: "System.Reflection.MissingMetadataException" в Newtonsoft.Json.dll
Дополнительные сведения: Reflection_InsufficientMetadata_NoHelpAvailable: EETypeRva:0x0001e930. For more information, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=623485

Исключение типа "System.Reflection.MissingMetadataException" возникло в Newtonsoft.Json.dll, но не было обработано в коде пользователя
Дополнительные сведения: Reflection_InsufficientMetadata_NoHelpAvailable: EETypeRva:0x0001e930. For more information, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=623485

Вызвано исключение: "System.Reflection.MissingMetadataException" в project.UWP.McgInterop.dll
Дополнительные сведения: Reflection_InsufficientMetadata_NoHelpAvailable: EETypeRva:0x0001e930. For more information, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=623485

Исключение типа "System.Reflection.MissingMetadataException" возникло в project.UWP.McgInterop.dll, но не было обработано в коде пользователя
Дополнительные сведения: Reflection_InsufficientMetadata_NoHelpAvailable: EETypeRva:0x0001e930. For more information, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=623485
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In release mode UWP apps are compiled with .NET Native tool chain. If you want using Reflection then you should add types in Default.rd.xml file [DOC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn600640%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: thanks, where I can found types which I need to use Reflection ? Can you give example, please?  Msdn give link on https://dotnet.github.io/native/troubleshooter/type.html but I don't understand thier terminology, I should choose All types in an assembly System.Reflection ?

Comment: And What I should choose "I use reflection to" and "I reflect on" ? I don't know..